# Open XML configuration to the Configuration XML rather than Message Flow

Tags: xml, mule, editor, settings, anypoint-studio

Is there a setting in AnyPoint 6.1.2 that would allow opening a config file directly into the Configuration XML rather than the graphical Message Flow?

[image: Configuration XML text]

I prefer to edit directly in the XML editor.

[image: Graphical Message Flow]

I have looked in Window/Preferences and throughout. I am unable to find a setting that would default to the Configuration XML tab.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not as far as i know. some colleague of mine started using the default xml editor provided by eclipse for the same reason. it has some drawbacks, but works surprisingly well.

things like **code assist** in mule expressions will be missing.

[image: mule configuration editor with code assist]
<sup>*mule configuration editor **with** code assist*</sup>

[image: plain xml editor without code assist]
<sup>*plain xml editor **without** code assist*</sup>

xml-related features like available elements and attributes and validation according to xml schema will work.

[image: available elements in plain xml editor]
<sup>*available elements in plain xml editor*</sup>

[image: warning because of empty flow]
<sup>*warning because of empty flow*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It's just simple.
You need to click right button on 'flow'.xml in Package Explorer and select open with XML Editor. It will open in XML Editor and when next time you dbl click on 'flow'.xml it'll be open in XML Editor too.
To change it back you need to change editor in "open with".

Answer (score 0):

In Anypoint Studio, there is no preference as per my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on any flow -> Open with -> Other -> Choose "XML Editor" and check "Use it for all *.xml files", when open again the view will have Desing and Source tabs.